# How to show users the code of a website?

Tags: html, edit, jsfiddle

I am trying to make a series of projects where I have users edit content of a website, but I'd like to **show them the code that's being edited in real time**. Similar to jsFiddle, or more similar to the way you can edit code in Tumblr themes. However, I don't want them to be able to edit any of the code, just see it.

Any ideas, tools, languages, etc, I could use for this?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe this is a start to what you are looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/966Ua/1/ Real time editing and viewing..

Answer (score 1):

Found an interesting way to do it, by pushing the HTML into a TextArea element, the entities will automatically be decoded:

```
var escape = document.createElement('textarea');
function escapeHTML(html) {
    escape.innerHTML = html;
    return escape.innerHTML;
}
document.write(escapeHTML('<html>'+document.documentElement.innerHTML+'</html>'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n25tD/

You may also find the [`contenteditable`](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/) attribute interesting for teaching them.